# How can I multiply 2 separate rand values within one argument in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, random, calculation

I would like to multiply 2 separate random numbers within an argument, to match the following (for example):

> rand(1..6) + rand(1..6)
>
> =>9   (result could be anything between 2-12)

I am in early stages of learning Ruby, so forgive me, but how do I achieve the same with multiplication? For example, the following will only multiply the same random number twice:

> 2 * rand(1..6)
>
> =>2   (will only produce 2,4,6,etc)

Which is what you would expect. But how do I alter that statement to signify 2 separate rand calculations within that range (giving me a possible value between 2 and 12)? Thank you.

EDIT: Solved by using @var **.times** the rand, then doing an element **.push**. This allows me also to display both results individually, as well as doing **.sum** to make the total.

Comment: I think your problem should now be solved in my final edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
2.times.sum { rand(1..6) }
```

or

```
(1..2).sum { rand(1..6) }
```

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is construct a random array and then sum its elements:

```
Array.new(2) { rand(1..6) }.reduce(:+)
```

This creates an array with two elements and populates each element by running the block. Since the block is run separately for each element, you get separate random numbers.

Comment: Thanks, this is interesting. I'll have a play around with this, I guess I was just assuming there was an easy bit of code related to rand itself that I didn't know about.

Answer (score 1):

It works much like it does for addition.

```
rand(1..6) * rand(1..6)
```

will first generate the two random numbers, and then it will multiply them.
The result for this example will be 1 at minimum and 36 at a maximum.

EDIT:

If you want any number 2-12 (with an even distribution unlike rolling two dice),

```
rand(2..12)
```

otherwise, there is really no reason to multiply anything. You should just use the addition that you have in your question.

EDIT2:

Now to the core of your question, you want to roll a d6 n times. In your function give this a try.

```
total = 0
n.times { total += rand(1..6) }
```

This will roll a die n times and add it to the total each time.

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I wasn't clear enough. It's akin to rolling a 6-sided dice 2 times and adding them together. But instead of manually coding 'rand + rand', I want to be able to duplicate that rand two times and gather the result.

Comment: My main reasoning is the number of dice rolls will be in a variable and passed through to the calculation, so I was hoping for something along the lines of >@var * D6 rolls = 1-6, 2-12, 3-18, 4-24 (depending on @var being 1,2,3,4). Looking at the other response I can see that pushing each dice roll to an array is an option for this, I need to play around with that..

Comment: Thankyou for Edit2. That's interesting, I'll have a play around with that.

Answer (score 0):

For just two numbers, `rand(1..6) + rand(1..6)` is probably easier to read. However, as the number of random numbers to be added together grows, something like this might be more appropriate:

```
2.times.map { rand(1..6) }.reduce(:+)
```

`2.times` produces a 2-element `Enumerator`.

`.map { rand(1..6) }` turns this into an array of 2 random numbers from 1 to 6.

`.reduce(:+)` adds all the elements of that array together.

See the docs for [times](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Integer.html#method-i-times), [map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map), and [reduce](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce).